# Python: Array(Matrix) to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I am stuck trying to convert my array into a pandas dataframe.

My output array looks like this:

```
[[1,2,4,n],[1,2,3,n]]
```

**Example output:**

```
[[0.04376367614879647, 0.04376367614879649, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.08096280087527355, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.04376367614879651, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504], [0.04376367614879647, 0.04376367614879649, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.08096280087527355, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504, 0.04376367614879651, 0.043763676148796504, 0.043763676148796504],...[]]
```

Now I would like to create a dataframe with columns for each `1..n` value.
What is the best way to tell pandas to do this?

```
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(my_array,columns=['first','second',...n]
```

I am having trouble reshaping this `my_array`, so pandas can understand.

Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `.T()` method does it:

```
In [8]:

arr = [[1,2,3,5],[2,3,4,6]]
print pd.DataFrame(arr, index=['col1','col2']).T
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     2     3
2     3     4
3     5     6
```

If your input is `numpy` `array`:

```
In [9]:

arr = np.array([[1,2,3,5],[2,3,4,6]])
print pd.DataFrame(arr.T, columns=['col1','col2'])
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     2     3
2     3     4
3     5     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe last time I didn't have the correct number of columns. It gave me 0 and 1 columns. works now. I guess that was the problem. Thanks for help, too.